# storing client datimetime with zone in postgresql table

Tags: datetime, flask, postgresql-9.4, pytz, timestamp-with-timezone

I want to store visitor last visit to my flask web page.

for which  I created db

```
class TempTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tempTable"
    timeStamp = db.Column(types.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    moment = db.Column(types.Time(timezone=True)) 

    def __init__(self, tsz, moment):
        self.timeStamp = tsz
        self.moment = moment
```

but since I want visitor datetime with zone to be stored in the `moment` column in above table, in my flask app I am creating datetime with timezone like below:

```
`datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(data["timezone"])).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z")`
```

and then punch the above into the `moment` column of `tempTable`.

However the confusion is I am creating string object but `moment` column stores date time object , so not sure I am doing it right!

or do I just have to punch the `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(data["timezone"]))` directly ?

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: updated after comments

```
import datetime

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from pytz import timezone
from sqlalchemy import types

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update({
    'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': "postgresql://user_pass_host_db",
})

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class TempTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tempTable"
    id = db.Column(types.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    moment = db.Column(types.Time(timezone=True))

db.create_all()

eastern = TempTable()
warsaw = TempTable()

eastern.moment = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime("%H:%M:%S %z")
warsaw.moment = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('Europe/Warsaw')).strftime("%H:%M:%S %z")
# save our records and check data from db
for i in [eastern, warsaw]:
    db.session.add(i)
    db.session.commit()

    last_moment = TempTable.query.order_by('-id').first().moment
    print('saved: time = %s' % last_moment.strftime("%H:%M:%S %z"))
```

Example output:

```
saved: time = 14:16:39 -0400
saved: time = 20:16:39 +0200
```

Records in db:

```
14:16:39 -04:00
20:16:39 +02:00
```

As you can see, you can do any manipulations with `moment` after extracting from the database.

By the way, in your case `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z")` does not matter because you use `types.Time`(time is not date) for field `moment`.

Comment: Yes I gave it a try earlier and it works. Thanks for your answer .? I believe time should always be saved in Utd with the time zone in db.

Comment: hello @Daniel, in the first utc time has utc timezone from PostGreSQL , so even if UTC timezone is punched into the `moment` column you cannot retrieve the actual time of the user becuase user timezone is not known, in second case we do have timezone but  its string formatted which I believe can mess up in case of daylight saving is on .  So I think something needs to be done here. As of now I have unchecked your accepted answer.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz oh. thanks for the feedback! I think I should remove my answer. Do you agree with me?

Comment: you have an option to improve over that. could be useful for others in the community

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz I had a little time. I updated the answer. Hope this helps